# How to compare these arrays in C#, and return values which are equal

Tags: c#, arrays, compare

I'm trying to make a program in C# that could be used to schedule meetings based on different peoples availability. Currently it will take the user data and put it into a text file, an example line would read "Name 01/01/2000 11" and there will be multiple lines. I think I've managed to get it to read this into an array, although am not sure how I could test this (e.g. output the array into a label?) and now need to compare the dates and times and output the dates and times that are equal. Here is some of the code that has done this which seems to execute fine and does update the file:

```
    System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"Times.txt", true);
    file.WriteLine(lineForFile);
    file.Close();
    string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"Times.txt");
    string[][] jaggedArray = lines.Select(line => line.Split(' ').ToArray()).ToArray();
```

Help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: you do not need a jaggedArray for starters.. when you do `line.Split(' ')` you will get back a string[] anyway.. and you don't need `ToArray()).ToArray()`

Comment: do a quick google search on the following `C# Stackoverflow File.ReadAllLines` you can see numberous examples on how to do this using the `string.Split()` method

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to approach this. But I would recommend introducing some typed class to help you out. Maybe start with a simple class called appointment:

```
public class Appointment
{

     private Appointment(string name, DateTime app, int id)
     {
         Name = name;
         Time = app;
         Id = id;
     }

     public string Name {get ; private set;}
     public DateTime Time{get; private set;}
     public int Id{get ;private set;} // Not sure if the 11 was an id or the time in your example.

     public static Create(string name, DateTime app, int id)
     {
        return new Appointment(name,app, id);
     } 
}
```

This class will help you when working with your data. So now you could get a list of appointments back from your data layer and create new instances of each appointment from your list of delimited strings (if you have to use a file for storage maybe look at using something other than a space to delimit the data (maybe a pipe | or a comma ,.). Another option is to go with a db or xml format.

```
   IList<Appointment> appointemts = File.ReadAllLines(@"Times.txt").Select(v => {var row = v.Split(' '); return  Appointment.Create(row[0],DateTime.parse(row[1]),int.parse(row[2]);}).ToList();
```

Now you can work with a type to apply some query logic:

From here maybe use a linq group to get a distinct list of dates that people have appointments for:

```
var appointmentsByDate = from a in appointments 
                         group a by a.Time into g
                         select new {Time = g.key, Appointments= g.ToList()};
```

You now have a dictionary which has a key of the time of the appointment and a value which is a list of appointments for that day/ time. From this you can do a simple query to identify conflicts , which is basically any list time that has more than one appointment.

```
var conflicts = appointmentsByDate.Where(a => a.Appointments.Count > 1);
```